# Why am I receiving 'TypeError: Object is not callable' when trying to append a class object to a global list from within a function?

Tags: python, typeerror

I want to append a class object (Yuman) to a global list from within a function but receive the error:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError 'Yuman' object is not callable

The exception only occurs when the append is within this specific function, when the same sort of append works in a different simpler function (The simpler function is at the bottom).

```
import dataclasses
import random
yumanList: list = []  # for storing Yuman objects.

'''a crude simulation of 2x2 Mendelian trait inheritance'''


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Yuman: # !!! THE CLASS IN QUESTION !!!
    Trait: str  # GG, Gg, gG, gg.
    Sex: int  # 1 is Male, 2 is Female.
    Breeded: bool


def reproduce() -> None:
    global Yuman

    # establishes all variables to be blank slates...
    _daddyTrait: str = "Unassigned"
    _mommyTrait: str = "Unassigned"
    _traitPool: list = []  # list of both daddy and mommy letter traits
    _childAmount: int = 0

# picks a random number used for indexing the _traitPool list.
    def _traitNumber() -> int:
        return random.randint(0, 3)

    # combines 2 separate indexed values from _traitPool.
    def _traitAssigner() -> str:
        _traitProduct: str = _traitPool[(
            _traitNumber())] + _traitPool[(_traitNumber())]
        return _traitProduct  # the combined 2 string values as 1 string value.

    # gets a trait from the male Yuman and adds to _daddyTrait.
    while (_daddyTrait == "Unassigned"):
        for Yuman in yumanList:
            if Yuman.Breeded == False:
                if Yuman.Sex == 1:
                    _daddyTrait: str = Yuman.Trait
                    Yuman.Breeded = True

    # gets a trait from a female Yuman and adds to _mommyTrait.
    while (_mommyTrait == "Unassigned"):
        for Yuman in yumanList:
            if Yuman.Breeded == False:
                if Yuman.Sex == 2:
                    _mommyTrait: str = Yuman.Trait
                    Yuman.Breeded = True

    for letter in _daddyTrait:  # adds daddy trait attributes to the pool...
        _traitPool.append(letter)
    for letter in _mommyTrait:  # adds mommy trait attributes to the pool...
        _traitPool.append(letter)
    random.shuffle(_traitPool)  # shuffles the pool
    # determines the amount of children to be born in _childAmount...
    _childAmount: int = random.randint(1, 7)

    for i in range(_childAmount): # !!! PROBLEM HERE !!!
        yumanList.append(
            Yuman(_traitAssigner(), (random.randint(1, 2)), False))  
# !!Exception has occurred: TypeError 'Yuman' object is not callable!!
   


# !!! SIMILAR FUNCTION BUT NO PROBLEM!!! appending the initial 20 Yuman objects to yumanList...
for i in range(20):
    yumanList.append(Yuman("Gg", (random.randint(1, 2)), False))

while True:
    reproduce()
```

I've tried to create an intermediary local variable like:

```
global Yuman
_yuman = Yuman
```

But it doesn't work.

I've defined Yuman as global within the function and not as global, but neither affects the problem. I've also tried to confine the append to a sub function of the function itself and then call the sub function but this is also doesn't work.

Comment: You have too many things call `Yuman` so it is confusing. If it is a variable then use the Python convention of lowercase names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loops:

```
for Yuman in yumanList:
```

The loop variable is called `Yuman` (same as the class name!). Pick another name instead so that `Yuman` does not get overridden.

Essentially what happens is that after the loop, the variable `Yuman` does not point to the class anymore, but to the last item iterated in the loop. Quick example:

```
>>> s = 'I am a string.'
>>> for s in '123': #notice, same variable name as the string above
...     print(s)
...
1
2
3
>>> s
'3'
```

The fix is, again, to rename the loop variable so something else:

```
>>> s = 'I am a string.'
>>> for a in '123':  #diff. variable name from above
...     print(a)
...
1
2
3
>>> s
'I am a string.'
```